# Solid whose rotational symmetry group corresponds to $\textrm{SO}(2)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: geometry, group-theory

Sorry to inundate the feed with a question quite similar to my last, but again I've been drawing pictures for quite a while with little success.  Does anyone have any idea how to represent the product group $\textrm{SO}(2)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ by a solid (corresponding to rotations only)?

Comment: A cone? $\phantom{}$

Comment: Doesn't that only work for SO(2), and not account for the x Z_2 part?  However, everything I'm saying could be entirely wrong :)

Comment: Two identical cones glued base to base (for the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor).

Comment: But that's not abelian is it?  Isn't rotating about the axis from cone point to cone point then flipping the glued cones is in general different from flipping then rotating?

Comment: What do you mean by a solid and how does the group act on solids?

Comment: Solid is just some 3 dimensional shape, e.g. cylinder, cone, cube, torus...the book I'm working with doesn't bother to define it, so I'd imagine the standards are pretty loose.  I guess to be more precise, they're looking for a solid whose rotational symmetry group (set of isometric, orientation-preserving mappings sending the solid to itself) is isomorphic to SO(2) x Z_2.  Anyone can feel free to phrase that better...

Comment: A circular rubber band that you can flip inside out? Not sure how it's possible to get an abelian subgroup of SO(3) that has SO(2) as a strict subgroup.

Comment: @p.s. Problem is that you can still rotate that about an orthogonal plane, thus screwing up commutativity again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment by p.s. mentioned, your first concern is to find the subgroup isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}_2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$, and there aren't any inside $\mathrm{SO}_3$: any subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}_3$ isomorphic to $\mathrm{SO}_2$ is the set of rotations around a fixed axis, and there are no other rotations that commute with all of them. You can find an appropriate subgroup in $\mathrm{O}_3$ (add the reflection in the plane perpendicular to the axis), but I don't think it is the subgroup of $\mathrm{O}_3$ defined by any *solid* (because a solid fixed by all rotations will automatically also be symmetric with respect to reflection in a plane containing the axis). This argument suggests that you won't even have much luck either if your solid is situated in a higher-dimensional space (in which case the $\mathrm{O}_3$ of the $3$-space containing you solid becomes the image by restriction of a subgroup of $\mathrm{SO}_n$).